# ArcGIS is not showing all the colors of TIFF image exported from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-10.0, landsat-8, land-cover, land-use

I am doing supervised classification in Google Earth Engine then export the output in .tiff format image.
For prediction works, I need to import those .tif images in the ArcGIS. But ArcGIS / ArcMap is not showing all the colors of the .tiff file.

In GEE picture is shown like this below with coloring all the 4 class.
[image: This is the exported picture from GEE]

but when I try to open this picture with ArcGIS / ArcMap it does not show all the colors of 4 classes.

In ArcGIS the Picture is like the below
[image]

Code for collecting the supervised classification .tiff image data from Google Earth Engine can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ac2a38a943ac78ab60494e1801f748bb
sample code for exporting from GEE:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
   image: classified.visualize({min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['0000FF', 'FF0000', '008000','FFFF00']}),
  description:'LULCCHAGLAIN',
  scale:30,
  region:roi
});
```

How can I import .tiff images in ArcGIS software as like as it was exported from the GEE with all the supervised classification coloring...?

Comment: Symbology is not always part of a raster. Have you tried to symbolize it in ArcMap?

Comment: @Vince Under the Symbology I can see only 3 options. I am not sure which one to choose to fix the color of the features/classes. 
screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/u7jZxy8

Comment: I don't have ArcGIS so I can't really verify, but are you sure you are assigning the correct bands to each value? i.e. the red band is actually using the red band, etc.

Comment: Another option is to not export your tiff as an RGB image (meaning you remove the command that says 'visualize', line 58, instead export it as a raster and then just assign the colors in ArcGIS